# Java - format Date only with slash based on locale

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, dateformatter

My code is

```
ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ja-JP"));
System.out.println(zoned.format(pattern));
```

And the output is `2022/06/13`, which is fine. But when I change the locale to `en-US`, the date is `Jun 13, 2022`. I want to have all locale-based date to only have numbers and slashes, like `2022/06/13`, `06/13/2022`. How can I do that?

Comment: I guess the stupid question is why?  Formatting a date/time for the user should respect the users locale formatting, because not everybody represents the date in the same (ie `3/4/5` has different meaning to different people in different locations).  If you're formatting the date for "internal" representation (ie for API calls etc), then you should really be using a ISO standard format - just saying

Comment: I suggest that your users will be happier with what you already have. If you insist, you can get a format pattern from `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern()`, identify the order of `y`, `M` and `d` and manually replace `yy` with either `y` or `yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```java
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
                .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ja-JP")); // or "en-US"
```